# Pass Parameter to LinqDataSource "OnSelecting" for Stored Procedure

Tags: linqdatasource

I'm building a semi-elaborate RadGrid where within my NestedViewTemplate I want to have a LinqDataSource that uses a Stored Procedure to get data from the database.

Here's what I have so far

```
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenID" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>' />
            <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" OnSelecting="LinqDataSource_Selecting">
                <WhereParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenID" PropertyName="ID" Type="String" Name="ID" />
                </WhereParameters>
            </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

any my Code Behind...

```
Protected Sub LinqDataSource_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs)


    Dim hdc As New DAL.HealthMonitorDataContext()
    e.Result = hdc.bt_HealthMonitor_GetByID(Integer.Parse(e.WhereParameters("ID")))
End Sub
```

but unfortunately `hdc.bt_HealthMonitor_GetByID(Integer.Parse(e.WhereParameters("ID")))` isn't playing nice...

> **Exception Details:**
>   System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Forget it, I had the "PropertyName" incorrect in the WhereParameters. `<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenID" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" Name="ID" />`  Basically I'm a retard... sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "PropertyName" was incorrect in the WhereParameters.

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenID" 
                      PropertyName="Value" 
                      Type="String" 
                      Name="ID" />
```